# MySQL Syntax to Get First Record for Each Group

Tags: mysql, sql

Have a table that is ID (PK), Email, Timestamp. Many records for each email. Want to be able to pull the first chronological record for each day (based on timestamp) for each email. ID may or may not be in chronological order, so can't rely on that. Having a brain fart on syntax to do so...recordset should include 1 record for each email for each day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySql this should work:

```
select
  tmp.id,
  tmp.email,
  tmp.date_val,
  min(tmp.timestamp)
from (
  select 
    id, 
    email, 
    timestamp, 
    date_format(from_unixtime(timestamp), '%e %b %Y') as date_val
  from email_table
) as tmp  
group by
  tmp.email,
  tmp.date_val;
```